# FB api /me/accounts returns empty array on 1 website and not the other

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I maintain 2 websites and each company has an FB page. I'm trying to have them create events on fb from their website.

I used EXACTLY the same code for each with the exception of an include that has the ap_id, secret key, and page id. I have set up the fb ap the same except for the app domain and the url.

One works and the other gets a permission error.

When I add

```
$accounts = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
```

and

```
$me = $facebook->api("/me");
```

and do a `PRINT_R` of each, the `$me` is exactly the same but the `$accounts` is empty on the site that gets the permission error.

The site that works, shows all the pages that I'm an admin for including the one that doesn't work. I can manually create an event on that fb page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the same access token in both places? If not, do they both have the `manage_pages` permission? if you're not sure a call to `/me/permissions` or using  [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will tell you

Comment: Igy, you are definitely on to something. I'm not using tokens. I create the event this way. 


`$ret_obj = $facebook->api($whereToPost, 'POST', array(
'name' => $master["title"],
'start_time' => $startTime,
'end_time' => $endTime,
'description' => $master["description"],
'privacy_type' => $event_privacy
));`


When I use /me/permissions, manage_pages (as well as a lot of others, are missing from the one that fails.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do check to see if the user has logged in and if not, ask for user permission with this: 


`$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array('scope' => 'create_event, rsvp_event'));`

Comment: Thanks for you help Igy. It took a little bit for what you were saying to sink in, but I fixed it by adding the manage_pages to login request and it worked like a charm.